Cylindrical shells and disc method yield different result for the same problem?
The Question is:
Find Volume created by revolving y = sqrt(x) from x = 1 o x = 4 around y axis
I don't know what am i doing wrong but i double checked every step and still both yield different answers. Aren't they supposed to calculate the same volume? The following link has an image of my solution as I'm not allowed to add images yet.

Thanks in Advance !

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The cylindrical shell integral you have written will compute the volume of the solid formed by rotating the shape with vertices $(1,0)$, $(4,0)$, $(4,2)$, and $(1,1)$ about the $y$-axis. To get the final volume, we have to do two modifications. First, we remove the volume of the cylindrical shell below $y=1$, with inner radius $1$ and outer radius $4$. This leaves us with a volume of $\frac{124\pi}{5}-15\pi = \frac{49\pi}{5}$. Then, we subtract this volume from the volume of the cylinder above $y=1$ with radius $4$, to get $16\pi-\frac{49\pi}{5}=\frac{31\pi}{5}$, which is the same answer as the disc method.
This hassle could've been avoided if you had simply taken the height of the cylinder to be $2-\sqrt{x}$ with the same limits, and then added to that the volume of the solid cylinder of radius $1$ between $y=1$ and $y=2$.
